# cordova 3.0 lite4cordova open a pre existing .sqlite database

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite, cordova-3

cordova 3.0, lite4cordova Cordova-SQLitePlugin, installed all test OK. Working.

Building a new version of a previously released App for iOS and Android, where data.sqlite is the name of the db.

I learned from documentation that .db is the name extension with lite4cordova but need to open and connect with that data.sqlite db.

I try some blind rename data.sqlite to data.db and so on just to see if there is connection, but no luck.

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "data"}); // not OK
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "data.db"}); // not OK
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "/www/data.db"}); // not OK
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "/www/data.sqlite"}); // not OK
```

xcode console while looking for "food" table

```
2014-03-04 17:03:40.372 MyAPI2[81436:70b] Good news: SQLite is thread safe!
2014-03-04 17:03:40.373 MyAPI2[81436:70b] DB opened: data
2014-03-04 17:03:40.374 MyAPI2[81436:70b] Error: no such table: food code: 5
```

is there a way to specify a path to data.sqlite ?

Comment: Been stuck with the same problem... :(